# Deployment ESXi VM Machine in Google Cloud Platform without migration

Tags: vmware, esxi, appliance

We want deploy a commercial software, that the provider send us in ESXi format (virtual appliance), in Google Cloud.

For not miss the warranty, we can´t modify this VM.

Please, could someone help me?, i am new in GCP.

Thanks in advance.
Juanma.

Answer (score -1):

First thing you want to know when deploying ESXi to cloud environments is if your cloud provider supports Nested Virtualization.  If you're deploying ESXi to a virtual machine that's a must have.

As of today, Google and AWS don't support nested virtualization.

Your options are:  Go to Azure, they have some specific servers that can support nested virtualization (DS3 and E3 Layers) or go to Bare Metal (Softlayer).

Comment: From my read of the question, the user isn't attempting to deploy ESXi itself but, rather, trying to deploy an ESXi formatted VM image file to Google Cloud.